# jqgrid - subgrid collapse on reloadGrid (parent grid auto reload)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

When I'm invoking the event "reloadGrid" event like this for subgrid

```
$('#subgrid_id').trigger("reloadGrid");
```

The parent grid is reloading as well collapsing the subgrid and delete all the subgrid HTML code.

How Can I prevent this behavior and reload only the subgrid?

I'm using jQgrid 4.5.2.

Comment: You should include much more details about what you do. What kind of subgrids you use? Is it grid as subgrid or not? Which `datatype` have subgrids and the main grid? Do you load *separately* grid data and subgrid data or you load all the data *from the server* at once (for the main grid) and you use the *local* data as subgrid data? ...

Comment: Thanks for replaying,
it's grid as sub grid that I'm trying to reload.
the datatype is JSON.
I load the grids and subgrids separately from the server using the dataUrl.

Comment: What I mean is: your code have errors, but one can't find the errors only from the description of the code. One have to see the code itself. If you execute `$('#subgrid_id').trigger("reloadGrid")` then **only the subgrid should be reloaded. Probably you construct subgrid ids in a wrong way and you have id duplicates probably you have some other from thousand possible problems.

Comment: gotya... are you sure that this kind of behavior is a result of an error?? it's a bit tricky to copy paste here the entire code cause it's symfony which returning arrays to JS and then building the entire jQgrid so it's a long function and not an hardcoded jQgrid that builds is. I don't see any errors in the console etc. Thanks 4 trying to help me though :)

Comment: You are welcome! In any way you should include the code of subgrid from `subGridRowExpanded` callback. Which id have every subgrid? Which id have the main grid? Which id have the rows on the main grid? How you assign ids of rows of the main grid and the rows of subgrids? Do you use `idPrefix` option at least for subgrid? It's really important option in subgrid scenarios. By the way you can use `triggerHandler("reloadGrid")`  instead of `.trigger("reloadGrid")`.

Comment: Hey Oleg, you were right I had some mistake with sub grid ID that I was trying to reload. the ID of the subgrid is been generated by the PHP according to some parameters to create it unique, followed your advice and now it's not collapsing.... If you'll post an answer I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should verify how you build id of subgrid inside of `subGridRowExpanded` callback. It you work with subgrids, it's extremely important to hold full control about all ids of subgrids and all rowids of main grid and subgrids. All the ids must be unique. You should construct the id of subgridgrid based on the first parameter of of `subGridRowExpanded` callback or alternatively by calling the method `$.jgrid.randId()` which returns unique id on every call.

I strictly recommend you to use additionally unique `idPrefix` option for subgrid. You can build the value of `idPrefix` option based on input parameters of `subGridRowExpanded` callback. The rowid will then build based on the id of data, but the ids will have the prefix. For example you can use the second parameter is `rowid` with some suffix like `idPrefix: rowid + "_s_"`. So if your ids of the data of the main grid are 10,20,30... and the data of subgrid contains ids 10,15,20 then jqGrid you will use rowids of subgrids: `20_s_10`, `20_s_15`, `20_s_20` for the subgrid by opening the row with id 20 of the main grid. I hope that I don't confuse you with the example. In any way I recommend you to open 2-3 subgrids of your grid and to examine carefully which ids have every subgrid and rows of main grid rows of subgrids. You should find no id duplicates.